# Why do I get electric shocks off anything plugged in?

Tags: electrical

I always get electric shocks off phone and laptop charges as well as light switches but when someone else touches the exact same thing they don't get shocked.

Comment: Does it feel like a buzzing or a single "snap"?

Comment: Have you ever been struck by lightning, or been exposed to radioactive waste, or gamma radiation?

Comment: Are you an avid swimmer? Water saturation of the skin will lower your natural resistance and you could feel a shock that some one els could not feel.

Comment: Interesting here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_capacitance   From Kris

Answer (score 3):

This is called electrostatic discharge (ESD) and is caused by static electricity.  You must be doing something to build up static charges on yourself, such walking around with socks on carpet.  When you touch something that is connected to your electrical system, that charge escapes into the system and you feel a spark.